# Importing Images on 7" LCD using Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino, lcd

I want to load different images to my 7 inch TFT LCD screen (SDD1963 based) from an SD Card and I'm not able to do it. I'm using the CTE Shield for Mega.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help.

```
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <UTFT.h>
#include <SdFatUtil.h>
#include <Importer.h>
#include "SPI.h"

#define BVS_13 10
#define BVS_15 12
#define BVS_19 14
#define BVS_22 18
#define BVS_28 22
#define BVS_34 28
#define BVS_43 38
#define BVS_52 53
#define BVS_74 78
#define BVS_112 122

UTFT myGLCD(CTE70);

const uint8_t chipSelect = 53; // SD CSpin 
#define FLASH_CS_PIN 52  //Flash CSpin
#define SPI_RATE 4

#define BUF_SIZE 256
static char name[14];
static char flash_memory_type;
uint8_t buf[BUF_SIZE];

unsigned long Location;
unsigned long address;
char IMAGE_FILENAME[] = "0.CTE";
unsigned int MAX_sector;

// file system
SdFat sd;

// test file
SdFile file;


ArduinoOutStream cout(Serial);

#define error(s) sd.errorHalt_P(PSTR(s))
void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(38400);
  SPI_Flash_init(FLASH_CS_PIN,SPI_RATE);
  myGLCD.SPI_Flash_init(FLASH_CS_PIN,SPI_RATE);
  myGLCD.InitLCD();
  myGLCD.show_color_bar(); 
  delay(1000);
  myGLCD.clrScr();
}

void loop() {
  myGLCD.clrScr();
  myGLCD.Swtich_LCD_TB_Bit(0);
  myGLCD.setColor(255, 255, 0);   
  myGLCD.setBackColor(0, 0, 0);   
  myGLCD.Set_character_spacing(1); 
  myGLCD.Put_Text("Image importer via SD card",5,5,BVS_28);
  char charBuf[1]; charBuf[0]=169;charBuf[1]=0;
  myGLCD.setColor(255, 0, 255);   
  myGLCD.Put_Text(charBuf,5,40,BVS_28);
  myGLCD.Put_Text(" Coldtears electronics",30,40,BVS_28);
  myGLCD.setColor(255, 255, 255); 

  if (!sd.begin(chipSelect, SPI_HALF_SPEED)) {
    myGLCD.Put_Text("SD Access Error",5,80,BVS_19);
    sd.initErrorHalt();
  } else { 
    myGLCD.Put_Text("SD Access OK",5,80,BVS_19);
  }
  delay(1000);
  if (READ_ID()==0) {
    myGLCD.Put_Text("Flash memory Error",5,100,BVS_19); while(1){}
  } else if (READ_ID()==1) {
    myGLCD.Put_Text("Flash: 32Mbit, Max Img location 799",2,100,BVS_19);
    flash_memory_type=1; MAX_sector=1023;
  } else if (READ_ID()==2) {
    myGLCD.Put_Text("Flash: 64Mbit, Max Img location 1823",2,100,BVS_19);
    flash_memory_type=2; MAX_sector=2047;
  }
  delay(1000); 

  if (!file.open(IMAGE_FILENAME, O_RDWR)) {
    myGLCD.Put_Text("file open failed",5,120,BVS_19);
    error("open failed");
  } else {
    myGLCD.Put_Text("file open OK",5,120,BVS_19);
  }
  delay(1000); 
  char temp_buf[10];
  file.read(temp_buf, sizeof(temp_buf));
  file.rewind();
  unsigned int ass=temp_buf[6]*256+temp_buf[7];
  Location=ass;
  //DO NOT edit this, or else it may overwrite Font data
  address=(Location+224)*4096;
  //DO NOT edit this, or else it may overwrite Font data
  unsigned long filesize = file.fileSize();
  unsigned long no_of_sectors = filesize/4096;
  if (filesize%4096>0) no_of_sectors=no_of_sectors+1;
  unsigned long no_of_page = filesize/256;
  if (no_of_page%256>0) no_of_page=no_of_page+1;
  if (Location+224+no_of_sectors>MAX_sector) {
    myGLCD.Put_Text("Not enough space",5,120,BVS_19);
    while(1){}
  }
  file.getFilename(name);
  myGLCD.Put_Text((String)filesize+"bytes, Filename:",1,120,BVS_19);
  myGLCD.Put_Text(name,200,120,BVS_19);
  myGLCD.Put_Text("Img location: " + (String)(Location) + "-" + (String)(Location+no_of_sectors-1),120,80,BVS_19);
  delay(1000); 
  unsigned char countdown=10;
  myGLCD.setColor(255, 100, 100); 
  myGLCD.Put_Text("unplug power NOW to cancel..",1,140,BVS_22); 
  myGLCD.Put_Text(String(countdown)+"       ",280,140,BVS_22);
  delay(1000); 
  while(countdown>0) { 
    if (countdown%2==1) myGLCD.Put_Text("unplug power NOW to cancel..",1,140,BVS_22);
    else myGLCD.Put_Text("                                                                                          ",1,140,BVS_22);
    myGLCD.Put_Text(String(countdown)+"       ",280,140,BVS_22);
    countdown--;
    delay(1000); 
  }
  myGLCD.setColor(255, 255, 255); 
  unsigned long temp_add = address;
  unsigned long m;
  String total_sectors = " / "+ (String)(no_of_sectors-1);
  for (m=0; m<no_of_sectors;m++) {
    WRITE_ENABLE();
    if (flash_memory_type==1) WRITE_STATUS_REGISTER(48); 
    else if (flash_memory_type==2) WRITE_STATUS_REGISTER(44); 
    delay(30);WRITE_ENABLE();   
    SECTOR_ERASE(temp_add);
    temp_add=temp_add+0x001000;delay(300);
    myGLCD.Put_Text("Erasing Sector: ",1,165,BVS_19);
    String displaya = String(m) + total_sectors;
    myGLCD.Put_Text(displaya,150,165,BVS_19);
  }
  temp_add = address;   
  volatile unsigned int counter=0;
  String total_page = " / "+ (String)no_of_page;
  for(unsigned long  z=0;z<no_of_page;z++) {
    unsigned int bytes_read=file.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (bytes_read!=256) {
      for(unsigned int z=bytes_read;z<256;z++) buf[z]=0xFF;
    }
    WRITE_ENABLE();
    PAGE_PROGRAME(temp_add,buf);
    temp_add=temp_add+256;delay(20);
    counter++;
    myGLCD.Put_Text("Writing Page: ",1,185,BVS_19);
    myGLCD.Put_Text((String)counter + total_page  ,150,185,BVS_19);
  }
  myGLCD.Put_Text("Write File OK, Display image soon....",1,205,BVS_22);
  delay(1000);
  WRITE_ENABLE();
  WRITE_STATUS_REGISTER(252);
  delay(100);
  countdown=5;
  while(countdown>0) {
    myGLCD.Put_Text(String(countdown)+"    ",300,205,BVS_22);
    countdown--;
    delay(1000); 
  }
  myGLCD.Load_image(0,0,(Location));
  delay(2000);
  file.close();
  Location=Location+no_of_sectors;
  address=(Location+224)*4096;
  while(1){}
  //disable this for batch files import
  //IMAGE_FILENAME[0]=IMAGE_FILENAME[0]++;
  //myGLCD.clrScr();
  //enable this for batch files import
}
```

However I keep getting errors:

```
    Image_importer.ino: In function 'void setup()':
    Image_importer:65: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'SPI_Flash_init'
    Image_importer:69: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'show_color_bar'
    Image_importer.ino: In function 'void loop()':
    Image_importer:80: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Set_character_spacing'
    Image_importer:81: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:84: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:85: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:91: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:95: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:97: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:98: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:99: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:103: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:107: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:124: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:127: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:128: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:129: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:134: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:135: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:138: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:139: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:140: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:156: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:158: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:175: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:176: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:179: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:185: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Put_Text'
    Image_importer:189: error: 'class UTFT' has no member named 'Load_image'
    Multiple libraries were found for "UTFT.h"

 Used: E:\Arduino\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\UTFT

 Not used: E:\Arduino\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\UTFT_MEGA

 Not used: E:\Arduino\arduino-1.6.5-r2\libraries\UTouch

'class UTFT' has no member named 'SPI_Flash_init'
```

Comment: Where did you find that code? From here; http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=154423.0  ?

Comment: You are obviously using the wrong/old version of the UTFT library. The compiler complains about missing functions in this class. Try to find the correct UTFT version.

Comment: Even after addidng the latest UTFT library it still shows the same error. Any other solutions.

Comment: Did you find the answer?